# Shiny Dashboard Character Slider input

Tags: r, shiny

I am using slider with character as the slider parameter (FY17Q1 to FY19Q1) and i am trying to plot a graph using ggplot. But i am not able to plot the graph. Need some help how to plot the graph while changing the slider.

I tried the reactive function, observeEvent , reactiveValues

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(sliderTextInput("Quarter","Select Quarter:" ,
                                choices =  (File2$Quarter),#To not repeat values in the slidertextinput if the values are not sorted
                                selected =  (File2$Quarter), #values which will be selected by default
                                animate = FALSE, grid = FALSE,
                                hide_min_max = TRUE, from_fixed = FALSE,
                                to_fixed = FALSE, from_min = NULL, from_max = NULL, to_min = NULL,
                                to_max = NULL, force_edges = FALSE, width = NULL, pre = NULL,
                                post = NULL, dragRange = TRUE))),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(solidHeader = TRUE 
          ,collapsible = TRUE,align="center",offset = 2,title = "RiskTier Vs Quater",status = "warning", plotOutput("k", height = "300px"),width = 6)
      ,


      box(solidHeader = TRUE 
          ,collapsible = TRUE,align="center",offset = 4,title = "RiskTier Vs Quater(%)",status = "warning", plotOutput("l", height = "300px"),width = 6)
    )))





server <- function(input, output) {
  # File2<- File2[-(28:30),]
 #  # File2$RiskTierDesc = factor(File2$RiskTierDesc, levels=c("High", "Above Normal", "Normal"))
 v <- reactiveValues(data = File2) 
 # 
 # observeEvent(input$Quarter,{v$mode <- "Quarter"})
 # # if(is.null(v$mode))
 # #   return()

  observeEvent(input$Quarter,{
    if(input$Quarter[1] == input$Quarter[2]){
      updateSliderTextInput(session,"Quarter",selected = c((input$Quarter[1]-1),input$Quarter[2]))
    }
  })

  output$k<- renderPlot({


    ggplot(v(), 
           aes(x=Quarter, y=Freq, group=RiskTierDesc, colour=RiskTierDesc)) + 
      geom_line(aes(size=RiskTierDesc)) +
      geom_point() + ylim(0,2500) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("red","orange","green")) +
      scale_size_manual(values=c(1,1,1)) +
      labs( x = "Quarter", y = "Frequency") +
      geom_text(aes(label = Freq), position = position_dodge(0),vjust = -1) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })

  output$l<- renderPlot({
    ggplot(v(), 
           aes(x=Quarter, y=FreqbyPercent, group=RiskTierDesc, colour=RiskTierDesc)) + 
      geom_line(aes(size=RiskTierDesc)) +
      geom_point() + ylim(0,100) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("red","orange","green")) +
      scale_size_manual(values=c(1,1,1)) +
      labs( x = "Quarter", y = "Frequency(%)") +
      geom_text(aes(label = FreqbyPercent), position = position_dodge(0),vjust = -1) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to get a dynamic plot for quarter to quarter.

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I am getting a straight graph whenever i am selecting any quarter range. But i want intermediate graph when ever i am selecting any 2 quarter in my slider.

Comment: @JK1185 Sorry wht do you mean by intermediate graph?

Comment: I mean to say current i am getting plot like a straight line Ex - If i am looking from Fy17Q1 to Fy18Q1 i am getting a straight line one with value for Fy17Q1 and the other one in Fy18Q1 but i want to see the intermediate values from Fy17Q1, Fy17Q2, ........ Fy18Q1. Thank you

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's really difficult to test possible solutions, but I don't see anywhere that you're selecting all of the data *between* `input$Quarter[1]` and `input$Quarter[2]`. Instead, you're just selecting those two points, which explains the graph you're seeing.